# Can someone suggest how to implement custom Django PasswordResetView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to send password reset link to only confirmed email address. And also user can request password reset link by searching by username or email address which is not available in default django. I have been trying and editing the default django password reset view and form for many days. But not working for me.

Comment: You need to show what you did and the errors you got.

Comment: What is the official way to customize password reset view. So that user can search account by username or email for sending password reset link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can extend PasswordResetView  from 
rest_auth.views
and do more logic in it 
as in example

```
from rest_auth.views import PasswordChangeView, PasswordResetView, PasswordResetConfirmView
sensitive_post_parameters_m = method_decorator(
    sensitive_post_parameters(
        'password', 'old_password', 'new_password1', 'new_password2'
    )
)

class PasswordResetViewNew(PasswordResetView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        try:
            if User.objects.get(email=email).active:

                return super(PasswordResetViewNew, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            # this for if the email is not in the db of the system
            return super(PasswordResetViewNew, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

in urls

```
    path('password/reset/', PasswordResetViewNew.as_view()),
```

Edit to answer "How to search by username for sending password reset link"

the default serializer for the PasswordResetView contains

```
email = serializers.EmailField()
```

this mean the end point will not accept any thing except email 
so we will do some tricks to make it accept chars so we can send user name to it

firstly we would extend 
PasswordResetSerializer from rest_auth.serializers 
and do some maintains

```
from rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class TestSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField()
    # here changed the email to accept any chars
    reset_form = PasswordResetForm()

    def validate_email(self, value):
        #here we will trick it be make email really have the email of the username entered

        mutable = self.initial_data
        self.initial_data._mutable = True
        self.initial_data['email'] = User.objects.get(username=self.initial_data.get('email'))
        # don't forget to handle exception for username that not in db
        self.initial_data._mutable = mutable
        return super(TestSerializer, self).validate_email(value)
```

and with a little bit changes in our view like this

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
#don't forget to import PasswordResetView, TestSerializer

class PasswordResetViewNew(PasswordResetView):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    # here we changed the default serializer to our new serializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.data['email'] = User.objects.get(username=serializer.data.get('email'))
        # here we trick it again and change the email with the email for the username entered
        serializer.save()
        # Return the success message with OK HTTP status
        return Response(
            {"detail": _("Password reset e-mail has been sent.")},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will definitely try this. Again thanks for making by job easy

Comment: you are welcome i have used this code for return specific JSON Response , So i think you can add your logic in post method and then call the super

Comment: One problem. How to search by username for sending password reset link.

Comment: i will add an edit to the answer to a full case code

Comment: done , it works for me if it works for you please accept the answer if not you can tell me what you get so I can help you